# ¿Cómo identificar que se ha salido de un componente en AngularJS 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy desarrollando un sistema con *AngularJS* y se ha generando un problema. Estoy intentando identificar en qué momento el usuario ha salido de un componente, ya que tengo un `$interval` en un componente, pero al ingresar a otra sección de la página y sale del componente en el que corre el `$interval`, ese sigue corriendo.

¿Cómo se puede detener el `$interval` al momento de salir del componente?

Answer (score 0):

> [Nota](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) Los intervalos creados con este servicio deben ser explícitamente destruidos cuando dejas de usarlos, ya que no se destruyen automáticamente cuando el scope de un controlador o directiva son destruidos. Es importante tener esto en cuenta y asegurarse de siempre cancelar el intervalo en el momento apropiado. Dejo un ejemplo para detallar esta situación.

Puedes usar `cancel` para limpiar el objeto `$interval`. Puedes cancelar el intervalo en el momento de dejar el controlador.

Para hacerlo necesitas añadir un listener al evento `$destroy` del `$scope`. Ahí puedes limpiar un poco todo, por ejemplo: cancelar intervalos, cancelar timeouts.

**Código**

```
//Dado que tienes un intervalo
var myInterval = $interval(function(){
   //El código de tu intervalo
}, 1000)

//Puedes registrar el handler en el mismo controlador del intervalo.
//En el momento en que se destruya el scope del controlador 
//Por ejemplo al cambiar de component
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    //Puedes limpiar el intervalo
    $interval.cancel(myInterval)
});
```